# How can I get rid of this border artifact on my element in Firefox?

Tags: html, css, firefox

In Firefox exclusively, this element has broken border-radius (?) artifacts. I can't reproduce the problem in other browsers, and the effect is pronounced when using specific colors. The artifact presents as the background color "seeping" beyond the border, this is apparent in the MacOS screenshot due to retina resolution, at more reasonable DPI it appears as little "bumps" of pixels on each corner of the box.

This may be hard/impossible to reproduce on extremely high DPI displays, I'm also unable to make it happen in Safari/Chrome.

Screenshots:

- [Firefox 107.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2RnuV.png) (presents as "bumps")
- [Chromium 107.0.5304.87](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHgf6.png) (does not present)
- [Firefox 107.0 MacOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HyVOZ.png) (presents as "seeping", the light blue border is intentional, look at the corners.)
- [Firefox 107.0 Linux, higher contrast](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObtdI.png) (presents as darker corners)

```css
:root {
  --blue2: hsl(210, 100%, 98.0%);
  --blue9: hsl(206, 100%, 50.0%);
  --blue10: hsl(208, 100%, 47.3%);
  --slate3: hsl(197, 6.8%, 13.6%);
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.broken {
  height: 48px;
  width: 48px;

  margin-right: 10px;

  background: var(--blue9);

  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: var(--blue2);
  border-radius: 0.375rem;
}

.broken-subtle {
    height: 48px;
  width: 48px;

  background: var(--blue9);

  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: var(--blue10);
  border-radius: 0.375rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="broken"></div>
<div class="broken-subtle"></div>
```

Comment: Per the CSS spec I don't think you can use rem units for border radius: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius and https://caniuse.com/?search=border-radius. Use px and/or %.

Comment: They look the same? What am I suppose to be looking at?

Comment: @gre_gor it only really is visible at certain DPI on FF, currently trying to figure out if it's linux specific. look at my screenshot of FF for an obvious case of the issue.

Comment: Ah, my monitor is just crap. I see blurred rounded corner on the other monitor. I see it on Windows. Explicitly describing the artifact in the question would be helpful.

Comment: @gre_gor I've updated the post to contain explicit descriptions of how it presents in each of the screenshots. I've also verified the issue is not OS related, it presents in FF MacOS as well, albeit with different artifact.

Comment: @NathanielFlick using "6px" explicitly does not fix the issue.

Comment: Hi @endigma the only thing I can see are the different blue colours; the first one blue2 is 98% transparent...the border is there on the left you just can't see it.

Comment: I'm aware, please look at the screenshots if you're finding it hard to reproduce on your display.

Comment: @endigma Even with screenshots, visibility would depend on the screen contrast.

Comment: @gre_gor I've added another screenshot with a higher contrast border, the issue becomes less obvious as the border color approaches the box color.